# Code creating more swing Timer instances than needed

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am having issues with the swing Timer, watching other questions the problem seems that I have more Timer instances that needed because it speeds up every time I call "Timer(... , ...).start();" But I still can't understand how they create.

The part of code using Timer gets executed when a certain JButton gets pressed, I tried to make sure there won't be a new event while the timer is still running but it doesn't work.
Here's the part of code:

```
int delay;
ActionListener task;
loginCounter++;

if (loginCounter == 3) {
    LoginUnsuccesfulLabel.setText("A wrong password has been insterted three times, program sutting down...");
    LoginUnsuccesfulLabel.repaint();

    try {
        FileWriter w = new FileWriter(filepath + "report.log", true);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        w.write(dtf.format(now) + " >>> [Unsccessful Login]\n");
        w.flush();
        w.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    delay = 3000;
    task = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LoginButton.setEnabled(true);
            LoginUnsuccesfulLabel.setText("");
            LoginUnsuccesfulLabel.repaint();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };
} else {
    LoginUnsuccesfulLabel.setText("Wrong password.");
    LoginUnsuccesfulLabel.repaint();
    delay = 1000;
    task = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LoginButton.setEnabled(true);
            LoginUnsuccesfulLabel.setText("");
            LoginUnsuccesfulLabel.repaint();
        }
    };
}

LoginButton.setEnabled(false);
new Timer(delay, task).start();
```

Thanks to everyone :)

Comment: You have code that's not working as you expect, you don't know exactly where the bug is or what is causing it (else you wouldn't be posting a question here), and you've posted some code snippets, but how can you be 100% sure that the code you've posted is enough to allow us to understand and solve your problem? You can't be sure, and so best to create and post a [mre] program with your question. Please read the link as it will fully explain this useful tool, how it can help, how to create one, and all the details that you'll want to know.

Comment: Note, that you should create a `Timer timer` variable, assign the `new Timer(delay, task);` to it, then call `timer.setRepeats(false)`; before calling `timer.start()` on the Timer. This way, the task won't keep being repeated every 1000 seconds if the login is unsuccessful.

Comment: Note 2: why are you even using a Timer/delay here?

Comment: *the problem seems that I have more Timer instances* - look like you keep invoking `new Timer(...).start()` every time you click the button. The Timer should NOT be created in your ActionListener. The Timer should be created in the constructor of your class. You can then invoke the start() method when you click the button.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I needed to show a message for "delay" ms, I'm sorry if i wasn't clear, I'm new to posting :C

Comment: @camickr oh I see, ty so much